# Aceptar solamente todas las subexpresiones regulares

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo una palabra, por ejemplo, `hola`, y quiero hacer una expresión regular que acepte todas las subexpresiones. Es decir, tiene que aceptar `h`, `ho`, `hol` y `hola`.

Para esto hago `^(hola)|(hol)|(ho)|(h)$` ¿Hay una manera sin repetir las letras? ¿Cuál sería?

Si hago `^h?o?l?a?$` acepta todas las subexpresiones, pero tiene el problema de que también acepta `ha`, que no es una subexpresión.

Código que genera la expresión regular general:

```js
function generar_subexpresión(expresión)
{
  var salida = ""
  var subexpresión = expresión
  for(var i=0;i<expresión.length;i++)
  {
    if(i>0){salida+="|"}
    salida += "(" + subexpresión.join("") + ")"
    subexpresión = subexpresión.slice(0,-1)
  }
  return "^" + salida + "$"
}
var palabra = "hola".split("")
var resultado = generar_subexpresión(palabra)
console.log(resultado)

palabra = ["\\d","[a-z]","3"]
resultado = generar_subexpresión(palabra)
console.log(resultado)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Genera los grupos de esta forma `(?:x|$)`, significa que encuentra esta letra exacta o es el final de la expresión, así sí respeta el orden de las letras.

```js
function generar_subexpresion(expresion) {
  return '^' + expresion
                .split('')
                .map(x => `(?:${x}|\$)`)
                .join('');
}

var texto = generar_subexpresion('hola');
console.log(texto);

var regex = new RegExp(texto);

var pruebas = ['hola', 'hol', 'ho', 'h', 'hoa', 'hla', 'ha'];

for (var i = 0; i < pruebas.length; i++) {
  console.log(pruebas[i], ':', regex.test(pruebas[i]));
}
```